# How can I type ª on a Latin American keyboard on Windows?

Tags: windows-7, windows, keyboard-layout

How can I type the feminine ordinal indicator `ª` (U+00AA) on the Latin American keyboard layout on Microsoft Windows (7 Professional)?

I can get the masculine indicator `°` with <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>`</kbd> (i.e., <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>the key left of <kbd>1</kbd></kbd>) but I can't find the feminine indicator anywhere. Is there a way to type this, or, better yet, to find out *how* to type it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "latam" keyboard has a lot of hidden keystrokes:

[Alt Gr] + [Shift] + f = ª
However, you need a font that can show the characters.

Font in this image is: monofur

https://www.dropbox.com/s/y9fb4auvjqv4s91/latam_keyboard.jpg?dl=0

I know this is old but the choice marked most correct isn't.

[Alt Gr] = right [Alt] key

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Do you know where I could find a comprehensive list of these "hidden keystrokes"?

Answer (score 0):

You can view (grainy low-res) [interactive keyboard layouts here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/goglobal/bb964651.aspx). Wikipedia has various Latin-script keyboard layouts on its [QWERTY](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QWERTY) page.

From those, there is no feminine ordinal on the Latin American keyboard. It's on the Spanish (Spain) keyboard, which is supposedly now preferred.

Answer (score 0):

From [How to enter Unicode characters in Microsoft Windows](http://www.fileformat.info/tip/microsoft/enter_unicode.htm)

This method works regardless of any of your language settings.

- Press and hold down the <kbd>Alt</kbd> key.
- Press the <kbd>+</kbd> key on the numeric keypad.
- Type the hexidecimal unicode value.
- Release the <kbd>Alt</kbd> key.

This appears to require a registry setting.
Under `HKEY_Current_User/Control Panel/Input Method`, set `EnableHexNumpad` to "1". If you have to add it, set the type to be `REG_SZ`.

There's more methods on that page but this is the most universal one.